# How to launch my swf game in my manifest.json file for my Chrome packaged web app?

Tags: json, flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm struggling to get my first Flash game on the Chrome store as packaged web app.

All the tutorials I manage to find online are old and obsolete, or missing crucial info for a noob like me.

This is what I have so far for my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Snappy Turtle",
  "description": "Swim dangerous waters.",
  "version": "1.8",
  "manifest_version": 2,
   "app": {
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "favicon.png", "128": "icon.png" }
}
```

Somewhere in the mix I need something like the following so it will actually launch my game:

```
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "index.html"
    }
  },
```

but any way I try to add it I get errors, and of course, if I leave it out, no error report, but then the game wont run. ;)

Can any of you kind people who actually know what they're doing please point out to me the proper way to add this crucial bit in a way that chrome will actually accept?

Comment: Top half good. Bottom half "launch", delete it all. It should all be in you background.js file. I have got mine to launch with this. BUT, I haven't found out why my flash object isn't loading into the window. It all there except for the actual swf file. Have you since got it to work?

Comment: One more thing I learned. Once you try to install it with the "Legacy Code" it will try to install it as "Extension". You have to leave it and unpublish it if possible and start a new upload. But before any of that, open chrome://extensions and check Developer mode and Load extension from the folder and make sure it works even before trying to publish. That's the place I am now but the flash swf file is holding me up.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a (new) Chrome App.

From [Disabled Web Features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated):

> **Disabled:** Flash
>   **Workaround:** Use HTML5 Platform.

You might get it working by embedding an external page in a `<webview>`, but I doubt it will work - my guess is that the ban extends to webview content.

FYI, all flash game "apps" in the Chrome Web Store are not Chrome Apps, but *hosted apps* (also called *installable web apps*). Note that the documentation for them is [currently broken](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243724#c6), there are still traces at [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple).

Comment: This is not entirely true. They are now called Packaged Apps, or with a minor tweak, Chrom Apps. They do not have to be Hosted Apps at all; that's only if you want to host a Chrome App on your own website and use the Chrome API. There is a Legacy of code that doesn't suffice any longer, but with a small modification they are still Packaged Apps/Chrome Apps.

Comment: @ejbytes When I said "all", I was perhaps generalizing too much. But a majority of game "apps" are hosted apps. Also, tangentially related, Chrome Apps are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it by doing this code:

```
<object>
    <embed src="file.swf" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
</object>
```